# Azure Function .net framework

Tags: .net, azure-functions

I tried to create an azure function in visual studio 2019 community edition.

It seems that it does not have any .net framework in the dropdownlist. Only v1 and v2 .Net Core. Is is possible to have .net 4.7 as an azure function?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could choose the V1, the V1 is the .Net framework version. Yo could check this doc: [Visual Studio runtime versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#visual-studio-runtime-versions).

[image]

And after creating the v1 function, I change the `TargetFramework` to `net472`, it will work so you could create the .net 4.7 function.